# Postfix (Message rejected: Address blacklisted)

Tags: postfix

I configured `Postfix` to send my emails using `Amazom SES` SMTP account.
Theres one specific email (acc@mydomain.com) thats is returning the error `Message rejected: Address blacklisted`.

When I send the email using `Outlook`, it works properly, but when by `Postfix`, it refuse.

Where can I check the blacklisted emails of `Postfix` and find out why it has been added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think this is happening on Postfix's end? SES is almost certainly where the blacklist lies.

http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx334TMAWDDN4OF/The-Amazon-SES-8220-Address-span-class-matches-Blacklisted-span-8221-Error

> Occasionally, as you send via Amazon SES, you will have your message rejected with an "Address Blacklisted" error. The error you have run into is not a type of enforcement on your account – you are not on an ISP blacklist, and the email address you’re sending from is probably just fine.
>
> This error means that or one or more of the addresses in the To, Cc, or Bcc field of the email you just tried to send is on our blacklist. This happened because an ISP returned an "email doesn't exist" type error (or hard bounce) for one of those email addresses in the past for ANY Amazon SES sender. **After we receive a hard bounce for an email address, that address stays on our blacklist for 14 days.**
>
> If you are sure that the address you’re trying to send to is valid, you can submit a blacklist removal request in one of two ways: via a Premium Support ticket or on the Amazon SES forum. For more information, please see the Amazon SES Developer Guide.